# I need to update a Oracle procedure via a .sql script

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I need to update a Oracle procedure via a .sql script. I know the procedure works because it is currently running on our server, but I need to update the procedure on a client's box.

I need to be able to hand them a .sql script which they will open and execute with Oracle SQL Developer, which will update the procedure, but when I try to create the .sql file and run the .sql file it fails, because it's trying to run the procedure.

I don't want the procedure to be run, but rather be created or replaced with the following updated procedure:

> ```
>     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateDBUSER(
>          p_userid IN DBUSER.USER_ID%TYPE,
>          p_username IN DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE)
>     IS
>     BEGIN
>
>       UPDATE DBUSER SET USERNAME = p_username where USER_ID = p_userid;
>
>       COMMIT;
>
>     END;
> ```

Comment: If you run that script in sql developer it will replace the existing procedure and will not change any data.  Oh, and why do you put this on the client box, surely an onlogon trigger run from the database would avoid this?

Comment: @kevinsky the procedure above is just an example I grabbed. The actual procedure is far different.

Comment: That does not change the comment that @kevinsky made. Just replace the source of your procedure with the one in your example procedure.

Comment: @Marco that is not an option. I suggested that, but they insisted on a .SQL script.

Comment: I do not see your problem. You just create a file with the SQL to generate the script and save it with a name that you choose and you send it to them. They run that script with the proper username/password and the procedure is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the ddl for the procedure. This can be done using sql-developer 'save to file'. Tell the client to start sql-developer, connect to the schema where the code should be written and have them run the script using 'start' or the equivalent for start '@' script_name
The sql script should be located in the directory defined in the preferences for Database>Worksheet>'select default path to look for scripts'

```
@your_script
```

or

```
start your_script
```

It works from the worksheet, very similar to sql*plus.